# gnome-terminal geometry ignoring position

Tags: debian, terminal, gnome

I like to add Ctrl+Alt+T as a shortcut to open the terminal, and I like the terminal to open in the bottom right corner of the screen. So, I always added the following to Keyboard Shortcuts on Debian:

```
gnome-terminal --geometry 80x25-0-0
```

According to X manual, the -0-0 in the end should place the window in the bottom right corner. Now that works in a Debian 10 installed on a PC, with Gnome 3.30.2, but it's not working on another Debian 10 installed on a Dell Laptop, also with Gnome 3.30.2. On the laptop, the terminal window appears randomly around the middle of the screen, as if no position was specified. If I change the size of the window (80x25), I notice that this is respected, only the position is not. How can I solve this? Have searched everywhere, but found nothing.

Comment: Do you perhaps have X11 on one of the machines and Wayland on the other? (Figure out by e.g. `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE`.)

Comment: @egmont Bingo! Then what?

Comment: Then you can either switch back to X11, or get used to window positioning not working (apps have no control over the position of their windows on Wayland, this is by design).